# Cannot disable MMS link sharing without creating Samsung account

Tags: samsung, mms, rich-communication-services

When I try to send a picture using the standard SMS/MMS app "Messages", my Samsung S20 does NOT send it as an MMS.

Instead, it sends a plain SMS with a web link to a deep subdomain of 3gppnetwork.org (for example https://ftcontentserver.rcs.mnc001.mcc288.pub.3gppnetwork.org/cs/...etc. ).

I found [these Samsung instructions](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/stop-sharing-photos-via-link-share/) on how to disable this "feature". But when I click on the "Off" icon to disable link sharing, I come to screen offering "Connect to your Samsung account" or "Continue with Google", and no other option to continue.

So how can I disable this without creating a Samsung account or giving Samsung access to a Google account, which should all be completely irrelevant to sending MMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

The phone sending SMS messages with links instead of MMS messages was due to RCS ([Rich Communication Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Communication_Services)). It was turned on by default in my new phone.

Because it was not enabled or not available on the recipient's phone, the messaging app was sending web links instead of standard MMS messages.

But the setting to turn it off is not in the Messages app itself. It's under the general "Settings", in

Connections > More connection settings > Rich Communications

It seems that the Samsung instructions about disabling link sharing and which required a Samsung account were about some other unrelated "feature", irrelevant to my real problem.